# Getting $this->File() returns empty class

Tags: silverstripe-4

I have a simple SilverStripe 4.0 `DataObject` that has an image (ie. `$has_one = array("Image" => Image:class)`). When attempting to get this object's `Image` I get an empty `Image` object instead.

For example:

```
function DoStuff {
    return $this->ImageID; // returns relationship ID (eg 123)
    return $this->Image()->ID; // returns NULL
    return $this->Image()->URL; // returns NULL
}
```

What on earth is going on?! I'm savvy with SilverStripe 3, so am stumped by this issue which is isolated to SilverStripe 4.

Answer (score 1):

Alas! It appears to be that whenever you upload (or migrate) assets they default to being unpublished. This is sensible, but not documented anywhere.

This is the reason why I was getting an empty `File` record returned - the expected record was unpublished.